# Laravel 4: Building forms for models with eager loaded data

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4

With laravel 4 you can bind to a model in your form.

For example, the following code would bind a form to a Post.

```
$post = Post::find(1);

Form::model($post, [
    'action' => ['PostController@update', $post->id], 
    'method' => 'PUT'
])
```

From what I understand, to keep a database well structured I would have a separate table for categories.  So, below I will eager load my categories into my $post.

```
$post = Post::with('categories')->find(1);
```

I would like to edit the categories in my form.  But how?

I imagine the html output would end up being something like:

```
<input type="text" name="categories[0][value]" />
```

... but again, what's the right way here?  I imagine this is extremely common as you'd run into it as soon as your content type is stored in more than one table.

Answer (score 2):

I did something similar to users/roles which I think has similar relationships to your post/categories.

In your PostController create/edit action, send in the object of all categories:

```
$categories = Category::all();
return View::make('post.edit')->with(array('categories' => $categories)) // truncated for brevity
```

In your View:

```
@foreach ($post->categories as $category)
    {{ Form::checkbox('p_categories[]', $category->id, false, array('id' => $category->id)) . Form::label($category->id, $category->name) }}<br />
@endforeach
```

In your PostController store/update action:

```
$post->categories()->sync(Input::get('p_categories'));
```

Also, here's a pretty well written article on the same concept.  [Making many-to-many relationships easy](http://alex.leonard.ie/2013/04/03/laravel-making-many-to-many-relationships-easy/)

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe he wants to create/update a category at the same time when creating a post.